# Aggregate Function/Group-By Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This query works (thanks to those that helped) to generate a 30-day moving average of volume.

```
SELECT x.symbol, x.dseqkey, AVG(y.VOLUME) moving_average
FROM STOCK_HIST x, STOCK_HIST y
WHERE x.dseqkey>=29 AND x.dseqkey BETWEEN y.dseqkey AND y.dseqkey+29
AND Y.Symbol=X.Symbol 
GROUP BY x.symbol, x.dseqkey
ORDER BY x.dseqkey DESC
```

However the performance is very bad. I am running the above against a view (STOCK_HIST) that brings two tables (A and B) together. Table A contains daily stock volume and the daily date for over 9,000 stocks dating back as far as 40 years (300+ rows, per year, per each of the 9,000 stocks). Table B is a "Date Key" table that links the date in table A to the DSEQKEY (int).

What are my options for performance improvement? I have heard that views are convenient but not performant. Should I just copy the columns needed from table A and B to a single table and then run the above query? I have indexes on the tables A and B on the stock symbol + date (A) and DSEQKEY (B).

Is it the view that's killing my performance? How can I improve this?

**EDIT**

By request, I have posted the 2 tables and the view below. Also, now there is one clustered index on the view and each table. I am open to any recommendations as this query that produces the deisred result, is still slow:

```
SELECT
      x.symbol
    , x.dseqkey
    , AVG(y.VOLUME) moving_average
FROM STOCK_HIST x
JOIN STOCK_HIST y ON x.dseqkey BETWEEN y.dseqkey AND y.dseqkey+29 AND Y.Symbol=X.Symbol
WHERE    x.dseqkey >= 15000
GROUP BY x.symbol, x.dseqkey
ORDER BY x.dseqkey DESC ;
```

HERE IS THE VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[STOCK_HIST]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
      dbo.DATE_MASTER.date
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.year
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.quarter
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.month
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.week
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.wday
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.day
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.nday
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.wkmax
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.momax
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.qtrmax
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.yrmax
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.dseqkey
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.wseqkey
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.mseqkey
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.qseqkey
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.yseqkey
    , dbo.DATE_MASTER.tom
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.Symbol
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.[Open]  as propen
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.High    as prhigh
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.Low     as prlow
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.[Close] as prclose
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.Volume
    , dbo.QP_HISTORY.QRS
FROM dbo.DATE_MASTER
INNER JOIN dbo.QP_HISTORY ON dbo.DATE_MASTER.date = dbo.QP_HISTORY.QPDate ;
```

HERE IS DATE_MASTER TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATE_MASTER] (
      [date]    [datetime] NULL
    , [year]    [int] NULL
    , [quarter] [int] NULL
    , [month]   [int] NULL
    , [week]    [int] NULL
    , [wday]    [int] NULL
    , [day]     [int] NULL
    , [nday]    nvarchar NULL
    , [wkmax]   [bit] NOT NULL
    , [momax]   [bit] NOT NULL
    , [qtrmax]  [bit] NOT NULL
    , [yrmax]   [bit] NOT NULL
    , [dseqkey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [wseqkey] [int] NULL
    , [mseqkey] [int] NULL
    , [qseqkey] [int] NULL
    , [yseqkey] [int] NULL
    , [tom]     [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] ;
```

HERE IS THE QP_HISTORY TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QP_HISTORY] (
      [Symbol] varchar    NULL
    , [QPDate] [date]     NULL
    , [Open]   [real]     NULL
    , [High]   [real]     NULL
    , [Low]    [real]     NULL
    , [Close]  [real]     NULL
    , [Volume] [bigint]   NULL
    , [QRS]    [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] ;
```

HERE IS THE VIEW (STOCK_HIST) INDEX

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_STOCK_HIST] ON [dbo].[STOCK_HIST]   
(
    [Symbol] ASC,  
    [dseqkey] ASC,  
    [Volume] ASC  
)
```

HERE IS THE QP_HIST INDEX

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QP_HISTORY] ON [dbo].[QP_HISTORY] 
(
    [Symbol] ASC,
    [QPDate] ASC,
    [Close] ASC,
    [Volume] ASC
)
```

HERE IS THE INDEX ON DATE_MASTER

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DATE_MASTER] ON [dbo].[DATE_MASTER] 
(
    [date] ASC,
    [dseqkey] ASC,
    [wseqkey] ASC,
    [mseqkey] ASC
)
```

I do not have any primary keys setup. Would this help performance?

**EDIT** - After making suggested changes the query is slower than before. What ran in 10m 44s is currently at 30m and still running.

I made all of the requested changes except I did not change name of date in Date_Master and I did not drop the QPDate column from QP_Hist. (I have reasons for this and do not see it impacting the performance since I'm not referring to it in the query.)

REVISED QUERY

```
select x.symbol, x.dmdseqkey, avg(y.volume) as moving_average 
from dbo.QP_HISTORY as x
join dbo.QP_HISTORY as y on (x.dmdseqkey between y.dmdseqkey and (y.dmdseqkey + 29))                          
                         and (y.symbol = x.symbol)  
where x.dmdseqkey >= 20000 
group by x.symbol, x.dmdseqkey 
order by x.dmdseqkey desc ;
```

PK on QP_History

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QP_HISTORY]
   ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_QP_HISTORY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Symbol] ASC, DMDSeqKey] ASC)
```

FK on QP_History

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QP_HISTORY] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QP_HISTORY_DATE_MASTER] FOREIGN KEY([DMDSeqKey]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DATE_MASTER] ([dseqkey])
```

PK on Date_Master

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DATE_MASTER]
 ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_DATE_MASTER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([dseqkey] ASC)
```

EDIT

HERE IS THE EXECUTION PLAN

Comment: Could you post the structure of the underlying tables and the view definition?

Comment: yes, please post what the view is doing.

Comment: I have moved your answer-post into the original question and formatted a bit. Could you, please, delete the post below.

Comment: I do not see primary keys on `QP_HISTORY` and `DATE_MASTER`. Did you forget to post them? Please add definition of any keys and indexes to the question section too.

Comment: Tell us about the `MASTER_DATE` table. How many rows can one day have in the table?

Comment: Hi I posteded the indexes. Sorry about the formatting I am new to this board and trying to figure that out. If I need primary/foreign keys, what is the proper syntax given the above definitions? Also on Date_Master it DSeqKey (identity) begins at 0, gets 1 new row each day and is currently at 20673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I'll start from the end. I would like to achieve this model.

[image]

With this in place, you can run the query on the history table directly, no need for the view and join to the `dbo.DATE_MASTER`.

```
select
      x.symbol
    , x.dseqkey
    , avg(y.volume) as moving_average
from dbo.QP_HISTORY as x
join dbo.QP_HISTORY as y on  (x.dSeqKey between y.dSeqKey and (y.dSeqKey + 29))
                         and (y.symbol = x.symbol) 
where x.dseqkey >= 15000
group by x.symbol, x.dseqkey
order by x.dseqkey desc 
OPTION (ORDER GROUP) ;
```

The `QP_HISTORY` is narrower than the `STOCK_HISTORY` view, so the query should be faster. The "redundant column removal" from joins is scheduled for the next generation of SQL Server (Denali), so for the time being narrower usually means faster -- at least for large tables. Also, the `join on ..` and the `where` clause nicely match the the `PK(Symbol, dSeqKey)`.

Now, how to achieve this:

a) Modify the `[date]` column in `dbo.DATE_MASTER` to be if the type `date` instead of `datetime`. Rename it `FullDate` to avoid confusion. Not absolutely necessary, but to preserve my sanity.

b) Add PK to the `dbo.DATE_MASTER`

```
alter table dbo.DATE_MASTER add constraint primary key pk_datemstr (dSeqKey);
```

c) In the table `QP_HISTORY` add column `dSeqKey` and populate it for matching `QPDate` dates.

d) Drop the `QPDate` column from the  table.

e) Add PK and FK to the `QP_HISTORY`

```
alter table dbo.QP_HISTORY
   add constraint pk_qphist  primary key (Symbol, dSeqKey)
 , add constraint fk1_qphist foreign key (dSeqKey)
                             references dbo.DATE_MASTER(dSeqKey) ;
```

f) Drop all those indexes mentioned at the end ouf your question, at least for the time being.

g) I do not see the size of the `Symbol` field. Define it as narrow as possible.

h) Needles to say, implement and test this on a development system first.

Comment: Thanks very much this is great. However here is a concern. The reason for the view is to avoid the complexity of dealing with dates that are non-contiguous. i.e. skipping Sat/Sun most of the time and other days at other times. I am ok w/avoiding the view but the original query would need to be rewritten to accomodate date vs dseqkey. What are your thoughts? Sorry I now see the rewritten query above. thank you.

Comment: One additional question. I have hundreds of queries/stored procedures written with dependencies on the column names in Date_Master. If I make the column name/data-type changes you prescribe, is there a way for me to auto-update all of the dependencies in the DB?

Comment: Not really, renaming that `date` to `FullDate` is optional. Because you use only date-portion of `datetime` changing this should not matter. The dSeqKey does not change.

Comment: @Damir - Please see my edits above. With the PK/FK between the two tables and using your revised query on QP_HISTORY-alone, it is slower. Is my syntax correct? Why do you suppose it is slower?

Comment: @Frank Zappa; can you post the Execution plan? Use "Display Estimated Execution Plan" or "Show Execution Plan", from the query manu.

Comment: @Damir - I just posted the XML version (SQLServer Generated) in the post above but it is not showing. I have the xml version and the "SQLPLAN" version in a file. How may I transfer to you? If you open the first question above and scroll to the bottom the xml plan is there.

Comment: @Damir - sorry the execution plan I posted had some temporary where clause restrictions that would not normall be there. I have a better execution plan to post but this website said I exceeded the character limit. The temporary where clauses were "Symbol = 'C'" and "DMDSeqKey >= 20500"

Comment: @Frank Zappa; try to post the graphical plan; place png somewhere and just insert the link into post.

Answer (score 4):

First, separate join an filter.

(edit: fixed ON clause)

```
SELECT x.symbol, x.dseqkey, AVG(y.VOLUME) moving_average
FROM
    STOCK_HIST x
    JOIN
    STOCK_HIST y ON x.dseqkey BETWEEN y.dseqkey AND y.dseqkey+29
                                AND Y.Symbol=X.Symbol 
WHERE x.dseqkey>=29
GROUP BY x.symbol, x.dseqkey
ORDER BY x.dseqkey DESC
```

Also, what indexes do you have - I'd suggest an index on (dseqkey, symbol) INCLUDE (VOLUME)

Edit 3: you can't have an INCLUDE in a clustered index, my bad. Your syntax is OK.

Please try these permutations... the aim is find the best index for the JOIN and WHERE, followed with the ORDER BY.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_STOCK_HIST] ON [dbo].[STOCK_HIST] (...

    ...[Symbol] ASC, [dseqkey] ASC, [Volume] ASC )

    ...[dseqkey] ASC, [Symbol] ASC, [Volume] ASC )

    ...[Symbol] ASC, [dseqkey] DESC, [Volume] ASC )

    ...[dseqkey] DESC, [Symbol] ASC, [Volume] ASC )
```

Comment: i think you're missing an ON part of the join there. or was that intentional?

Comment: @user: swap the order, make the index on `(symbol, dseqkey)` instead.

Comment: Excellent improvement. Completed in 9m 15s. I have a clustered index on the view, and each of the tables. Plus I have additional non-clustered indexes on each table to prevent dupes of stock/date/keys. Here is the clustered index on the view: CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_STOCK_HIST] ON [dbo].[STOCK_HIST] 
(
 [dseqkey] ASC,
 [Symbol] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic: oops, thank you. @Quassnoi: I based this on the >= 29 filter + the ORDER BY: why symbol?

Comment: With your query (above) and the following index it now runs in 7 minutes. Any additional recommendations? I can live with 7 minutes but faster is always better. CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_STOCK_HIST] ON [dbo].[STOCK_HIST] 
(
 [Symbol] ASC,
 [dseqkey] ASC,
 [Volume] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @gdb: because there is a join on `(symbol, dseqkey)` and a `GROUP BY` on the same column set.

Comment: @Quassnoi: SQL is declarative: GROUP BY x.dseqkey, x.symbol is the same... @user590822: 1. try swapping to [dseqkey], [Symbol] (I disagree with Quassnoi) 2. move VOLUME to INCLUDE 3. try dseqkey DESC

Comment: Sorry - I do not know what "move VOLUME to INCLUDE 3" means. What is the syntax?

Comment: @gbn: thanks for letting me know that `SQL` is declarative. If we want to find all records in `y` between `(x.status, x.dseqkey)` and `(x.status, x.dseqkey + 29)`, what index should we use?

Comment: @gbn: which both ways? An index cannot be used on a trailing column if the predicate on a leading is a range.

Comment: @gbn: `ASC / DESC` won't matter here since `symbol` is used in an equijoin and not used in `ORDER BY`. But let the @op try of course.

Comment: I used your edited query (thank you). I tested this query on a small data set (2 symbols) and the calculated results are spot-on. However, on the larger data-set the run-time is significantly longer (currently 40 minutes and counting). I mention this only to point out that the 7 minute run-time referred to earlier was likely an anomaly. Anyway, I will try each of the clustered index permutations prescribed above and let you know. Just wanted to let you know it is going to take a while. Permutation 1 ([Symbol] ASC, [dseqkey] ASC, [Volume] ASC) is running right now.

Comment: It ran over an hour so I killed the query and back the number of rows it analyzes to a smaller number so I could collect the index perf stats. The 2nd and 4th index configs are invalid - SQL doesn't like columns to be duped. Here are the stats:--...[Symbol] ASC, [dseqkey] ASC, [Volume] ASC ) 1 min 15 sec - 298531 rows on > 20640
--...[dseqkey] ASC, [dseqkey] ASC, [Volume] ASC ) cannot use duplicate columns
--...[Symbol] ASC, [dseqkey] DESC, [Volume] ASC ) 1 min 21 sec - 298531 rows on > 20640
--...[dseqkey] DESC, [dseqkey] ASC, [Volume] ASC ) cannot use duplicate columns

Comment: @user590822: my bad, copy/paste error for indexes 2 and 4. The results for 1 and 3 are the same effectively (without seeing the plan)

Comment: Looks like index with Symbol ASC, DSeqKey ASC and Volume ASC is the most efficient. However, this query will still run at least an hour and likely more. Any additional suggestion to cut the run time? Would the est. execution plan help to diagnose?

Answer (score 3):

`SQL Server` does not support `LAG` or `LEAD` clauses available in `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL`, neither does it support session variables like `MySQL`.

Calculating aggregates against moving windows is a pain in `SQL Server`.

So God knows I hate to say this, however, in this case a `CURSOR` based solution may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a clustered index on the view. that will make the view persisted to disk like a normal table and your tables won't have to be accessed every time.

that should speed things up a bit.

for better answer please post the link to your original question to see if a better solution can be found.